# DB2 multiple statements in THEN

Tags: sql, db2, dashdb

I would like my THEN statement to do something like

```
MERGE INTO ...
USING (...)
WHEN true
THEN [Update 1] AND [Update 2]
```

What is the proper syntax to achieve this?

I apologize, I should have been clearer.

**Thanks for your time!**

Comment: Is this a part of a SELECT/UPDATE/DELETE, or a part of a stored procedure?

Comment: @jarlh there should be two updates

Comment: what platform & version of DB2?

Comment: What are those "update 1" and "update 2"? Can you provide a better example? If you are trying to update two tables with a single merge statement, that's not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
CASE 
 WHEN condition
    statement1;
    statement2;
 ELSE    
    else_statement;
END CASE;
```

Please note the difference between case [expression](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_caseexpression.html)/[statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_casestatement4externalsqlpl.html).

Comment: I apologize, I should've been more specific, please check updated question. @lad2025 It seems your solution won't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Two `case` expressions:

```
(Case When true Then [Statement 1] end),
(case when true then [Statment 2] end)
```

As with all *expressions*, a `case` expression only returns one value.